# Freeze UI with Threads

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a timer to make a thread:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'ListBox2.Items.Add("Hilo")
    hiloCertificador1 = New Thread(AddressOf crearObjeto1)
    hiloCertificador1.IsBackground = True
    hiloCertificador1.Start()
End Sub
Public Sub crearObjeto1()
    UpdateList()
End Sub
Private Delegate Sub UpdateListDelegate()
Private Sub UpdateList()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New UpdateListDelegate(AddressOf UpdateList))
    Else
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection(parametrosCon)
        Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM COLA WHERE docentry < 8654 and enviado = 0", conn)
        Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        cmd.Connection.Open()
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dataSet, "Query")
        For Each fila As DataRow In dataSet.Tables(0).Rows
            cmd = New SqlCommand("UPDATE COLA SET enviado = 1 WHERE DOCENTRY = (@docEntry)  AND TIPO = (@tipodoc)", conn)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docEntry", fila("docentry"))
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipodoc", fila("tipo"))
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Dim factura As New FacturaCerificacion(fila("docentry"), fila("tipo"))
        Next
        cmd.Connection.Close()
        dataSet.Tables("Query").Clear()
    End If
End Sub
```

The timer have a 4000 interval, but when a thread start freeze my UI, I think is because the process is so big or the querys but i need make it without freezing.

Comment: Do you know what `InvokeRequired`/`BeginInvoke` *do*? They make sure you're back on the UI thread. It's not clear from this code when, if at all, it should actually be trying to go back onto the UI thread. It's unlikely it's whilst running the query and processing the results, but it's even clearer it shoudn't be *the first thing you do*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment is correct, and I will describe for you the issues hinted therein

**Using a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`**

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
```

This will run on the UI thread, and is only appropriate when doing UI things (even then, I am not sure you can really make a case for it over `System.Threading.Timer`)

**Creating a new `System.Threading.Thread`**

```
hiloCertificador1 = New Thread(AddressOf crearObjeto1)
hiloCertificador1.IsBackground = True
hiloCertificador1.Start()
```

This now runs off the UI, and is the entire contents of the Timer.Tick. So you've ticked on the UI then created a new thread off the UI. This is very odd

**Calling a Sub to call a Sub**

```
Public Sub crearObjeto1()
    UpdateList()
End Sub
Private Sub UpdateList()
    ' do stuff
End Sub
```

The redundancy should be self-evident

**Doing non-UI stuff but following the `Control.InvokeRequired/BeginInvoke` pattern**

```
Private Delegate Sub UpdateListDelegate()
Private Sub UpdateList()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.BeginInvoke(New UpdateListDelegate(AddressOf UpdateList))
    Else
        ' looks like a bunch of non-UI stuff
    End If
End Sub
```

This pattern is used for doing things on the UI but there seems to be no UI code in that block.

**Not using `Using` to ensure proper disposal of `IDisposable` objects**

```
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(parametrosCon)
Dim cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM COLA WHERE docentry < 8654 and enviado = 0", conn)
Dim da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
' do stuff
cmd.Connection.Close()
DataSet.Tables("Query").Clear()
```

Nongermane to your current issue, but also important to know.

**Solution**

So although it looks like a noble effort, you seem to be going back and forth between UI and not for no reason at all, or more accurately, creating issues where none existed with some over-engineering. The whole thing can be simplified with some minor changes

Use `System.Threading.Timer`

```
Dim Timer2 As New System.Threading.Timer(Sub() UpdateList(), Nothing, -1, -1)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' done in Form_Load if your Timer1 is Enabled in designer
    ' or can be done in a Button.Click, or however you had enabled Timer1
    Timer2.Change(2000, 4000) ' this will enable Timer after 2 seconds, then will tick every 4 seconds
    'Timer2.Change(-1, -1) ' this is how it's disabled
End Sub
```

Just call this method, and use `Using` to properly dispose your database objects. Added a `Sub DoUiStuff()` which is how the pattern is properly implemented

```
Private Sub UpdateList()
    Timer2.Change(-1, -1)
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(parametrosCon)
        conn.Open()
        Using cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 * FROM COLA WHERE docentry < 8654 and enviado = 0", conn)
            Using da As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                da.Fill(DataSet, "Query")
                For Each fila As DataRow In DataSet.Tables(0).Rows
                    Using cmdInner = New SqlCommand("UPDATE COLA SET enviado = 1 WHERE DOCENTRY = (@docEntry)  AND TIPO = (@tipodoc)", conn)
                        cmd.Connection.Open()
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docEntry", fila("docentry"))
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipodoc", fila("tipo"))
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                        Dim factura As New FacturaCerificacion(fila("docentry"), fila("tipo"))
                    End Using
                Next
            End Using
        End Using
        DoUiStuff(arguments) ' for example, if you need to update a GridView
        DataSet.Tables("Query").Clear()
    End Using
End Sub

Private Sub DoUiStuff(arguments As Whatever)
    If Me.InvokeRequired() Then
        Me.Invoke(New Action(Of Whatever)(AddressOf DoUiStuff), arguments)
    Else
        ' do UI stuff with arguments
    End If
    Timer2.Change(2000, -1)
End Sub
```

Finally, so I'm not contradicting myself, I'll add the Dispose method to dispose of the Timer. This Sub will be by default in your Form.Designer.vb file which you can leave there or move it to Form.vb once you add to it.

```
'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()>
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing Then
            components?.Dispose()
            Timer2?.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Now i having a error and is the thread are using the same query in diferent thread, before i had this error but with the thread.start() it start a diferent thread with diferent query every 4 seconds.

Comment: Set the indices correctly in your database. More than 4 seconds execution time to get a single record points into the direction of a full table scan...

Comment: I have 4 seconds because its the less time to the UI not freeze completly not for the query, if i can i set the timer every second but for the ux i set in 4 seconds

Comment: @MarioBraham check `Sub UpdateList` in my answer, I added a timer stop upon entering the sub, and timer start when exiting. This method ensures that the timer doesn't tick again while processing, and runs 2 seconds after completion.

Comment: The problem is i need to make the program without stop the timer in this case because i need make 3 or 4 thread async, i gonna try with a background worker and make the timer thread inside with a more threads. I have a labyrinth in my head, sorry

Comment: @MarioBraham sorry this doesn't solve the problem, but if you have more to it than you post in the question then it's very hard to solve it with an answer. It sounds like there are probably better ways to do what you want to do with Task.Parallel or Async/Await/Join etc.

Comment: @djv no problem, i have 3 days with this problem, and i am asking the best way, my program need to 1 click to start a timer and this make all the threads necesary for each diferent query response, but i cant stop the timer because i need the less time possible

Comment: @MarioBraham look into Task.Parallel or Async/Await/Join, try to solve it, and come back with another question.